# Pythonic Django Form Charfield CSS

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-1.8

I have a Django Charfield form that I would like to change via CSS. I want to change it in 2 ways.

```
 1. Width = 300 (solution below)
 2. Submit button inline with the input field (no idea)
```

`forms.py:`

```
class SheetForm(forms.Form):
    sheet_lookup = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
```

served in my `index.html`  template:

```
{% extends "check/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div>
<form method="POST" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Scan Here:</h1>{{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Scan</button>

</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

my `base.html`:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sheet Checker</title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Francois+One" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/main.css" %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Sheet Check</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a `forms.py` that works:

```
class SheetForm(forms.Form):
    sheet_lookup = forms.CharField(
                         max_length=30, 
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style':'width:300;'}))
```

But I don't think this is the correct way to affect the width change.

Also I am completely stuck on making the button inline with the input field

Comment: `widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style':'width:300px;'})` works for me. Note: "**px**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For width, you can do either what you mentioned, i.e. setting widget attribute in form, or you can do that in the template as given below-

---

### index.html

```
{% extends "check/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div>
<form method="POST" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Scan Here:</h1>
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        <input type="text" maxlength="30" style="width:300;" id="{{ field.auto_id }}" name="{{ field.html_name }}"/>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Scan</button>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

---

[This will help you understand it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template).

**EDIT (doing the same with css sheet)-**
You just use a class instead of inline styling.

```
{% extends "check/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div>
<form method="POST" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Scan Here:</h1>
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        <input type="text" maxlength="30" class="fixed-width" id="{{ field.auto_id }}" name="{{ field.html_name }}"/>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Scan</button>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and in you style.css

```
.fixed-width {
    width: 300px,
}
```

**OP Edit** - Fixed the formatting of from `{% field.errors %}` to `{{ field.errors }}` and `{% field.label_tag %}` to `{{field.label_tag}}` to work in Django 1.8

Comment: Awesome - thanks for your help! would there be a way to do this via a CSS sheet?